# Short story about an atheist dying, being resurrected by God in heaven to perform a mission

Tags: story-identification

I've read a short story, probably online, about an atheist who dies, and to his own surprise, is met by God.

The story is told from the perspective of the atheist, who learns that he was chosen because of his personality and way of thinking, and is asked to help finding a solution. In the story, it turns out that although God has complete control and understanding about our universe, there is something even He cannot do: affecting Himself, and His own eternal existence. Being curious about it, (or maybe hinted of God wanting to actually commit suicide, I don't remember), God gives the mission to the atheist to help in unlocking the limits of His own existence.

The atheist eagerly accepts the mission, the story ending with something in the like of it being a hard task to accomplish, but that's not a problem, he has all eternity to do it.

Comment: "Probably online"? was it a WattPad novel of some sort, or did you read the pdf online? How many years ago?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This sounds like ["The Last Answer"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Last_Answer) by Isaac Asimov. (Not to be confused with his better-known "The Last Question".)

From the Wikipedia summary:

> In the story, an atheist physicist, Murray Templeton, dies of a heart attack and is greeted by a being of supposedly infinite knowledge. [...] Templeton discovers that the Voice (in a classic counterargument to the logical regression of the First Cause argument for the existence of god) has no knowledge of his own creation. Templeton realizes that this, in turn, suggests he has no knowledge of his own destruction, and concludes that the only vengeance for this tyranny is also the ultimate vengeance, and resolves to destroy the Voice.
>
> At this epiphany and decision, the Voice reflects satisfaction, thinking that Templeton reached this conclusion rather faster than most of the countless beings currently trapped in the same condition, implying that the one thing the Voice truly wishes to learn from his thralls is the method by which he can be destroyed.