# Story about person who destroys the universe by disbelieving in it and helps God to commit suicide

Tags: story-identification

This is similar to [Short story about an atheist dying, being resurrected by God in heaven to perform a mission](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/158296/short-story-about-an-atheist-dieing-being-resurrected-by-god-in-heaven-to-perfo)
I remember a story about a man named *Walter Jehovah* who discovers that Bishop Berkely was correct and he can erase anything from the universe by "disbelieving" in it. He eventually "disbelieves in **everything**", including his body, and is confronted by God. He realizes that God set this up in order to commit suicide. He then disbelieves in God who disappears. He then tries to disbelieve in himself and fails. He wants to commit suicide, and finally thinks of a way: "*Let there be Light*".

What is the title and who is the author?

I forgot the name of the philosophical idea too.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

["Solipsist'' by Fredric Brown -- link to entire story](https://xpressenglish.com/our-stories/solipsist/)

I have never heard of this story. I simply Googled it. It was quite interesting, short -- micro-short.

Comment: Thanks I had forgotten the *solipsism* name and my googles kept giving me the wrong results.

Comment: @sabbahillel I googled the character name and just did not open any Jehovah's Witnesses links. It took less than a minute, but I did like the story.

Comment: Wow, that was shorter than half the answers here.

Comment: A bit of a rip-off of two Isaac Asimov stories there.